How in a crud page to make trix editor when form is uploaded by click?
In laravel 10 / livewire 3 app I have a crud page where editor with form was shown when
$updateMode var got 'edit' value assigned :
<?php

namespace App\Livewire\Admin;
...
use App\Livewire\Forms\NewsCategoryForm;
use App\Livewire\TrixEditor; // refrence to custom component

class CrudNewsCategories extends Component
{
    const EVENT_VALUE_UPDATED = 'trix_value_updated';
    FINAL PUBLIC CONST CLIENT_ALERT_TITLE = 'Admin News Category Crud';
    use WithPagination;
    use WithFileUploads;
    use AppCommonTrait;

    const storagePath = 'public/news_categories';
    protected $queryString = ['name', 'extended_search', 'active'];
    protected $listeners
        = [
            TrixEditor::EVENT_VALUE_UPDATED // trix_value_updated()
        ];
    public NewsCategoryForm $form;

    public string $updateMode = 'browse';

    public function render()
    {
        $backendPerPage = (int)Cache::get("backend_per_page", 20);
        $this->newsCategoriesDataRows = NewsCategory
            ::getByName($this->filters['name'], $this->filters['extended_search'])
            ->getByActive(NewsCategoryActiveEnum::tryFrom($this->filters['active']))
            ->withCount('news')
            ->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')
            ->paginate($backendPerPage);

        return view('admin.news-categories.crud-news-categories', [
            'newsCategoriesDataRows' => $this->newsCategoriesDataRows,
            'newsCategoriesRowsCount' => $this->getNewsCategoryRowsCount()
        ])->layout('components.layouts.admin');
    }

    public function edit($id)
    {
        ...
        $newsCategory = NewsCategory
            ::getById($id)
            ->withCount('news')
            ->first();

        $this->updateMode = 'edit';
        ...
    }


    public function trix_value_updated($value){
        $this->form->setDescription($value);
    }

    public function add($itemLabel)
    {
        $this->updateMode = 'add';
        ...

    }


    public function cancel()
    {
        $this->updateMode = 'browse';
        ...
    }

}


and in blade :
        @if($updateMode=='browse')
        ...
            Data in listing
        ...
        @endif

        @if($updateMode=='edit' or $updateMode=='add')
            @include('admin.news-categories.form')
        @endif


It worked ok, until I added trix editor support in my form with trix component app/Livewire/TrixEditor.php:
namespace App\Livewire;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Livewire\Component;
use Livewire\WithFileUploads;

class TrixEditor extends Component
{
    const EVENT_VALUE_UPDATED = 'trix_value_updated';
    const IMAGES_PATH = 'public/photos';
    public $value;
    public $imagesPath;
    public $trixId;
    use WithFileUploads;
    public $photos = [];

    public function mount($value = '', $imagesPath = ''){
        $this->value = $value;
        $this->imagesPath = $imagesPath;
        $this->trixId = 'trix-' . uniqid();
    }

    public function updatedValue($value){
        $this->dispatch(self::EVENT_VALUE_UPDATED, $this->value);
    }


    public function completeUpload(string $uploadedUrl, string $trixUploadCompletedEvent){
        foreach($this->photos as $photo){
            if($photo->getFilename() == $uploadedUrl) {
                $newFilename = $photo->store(self::IMAGES_PATH);
                $url = Storage::url($newFilename);
                $this->dispatch($trixUploadCompletedEvent, [
                    'url' => $url,
                    'href' => $url,
                ]);
            }
        }
    }

    public function render()
    {
        return view('livewire.trix-editor');
    }
}


and blade file :
<div wire:ignore>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/1.3.1/trix.min.css" />

    <input id="{{ $trixId }}" type="hidden" name="trix_content" value="{{ $value }}">
    <trix-editor
        wire:ignore input="{{ $trixId }}"
     ></trix-editor>


    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/trix/1.3.1/trix.min.js"></script>
</div>

<script>
    var trixEditor = document.getElementById("{{ $trixId }}")
    var mimeTypes = ["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg"];

    console.log('trixEditor::')
    console.log(trixEditor)


    addEventListener("trix-blur", function(event) {
        console.log('trix-blur  trixEditor.getAttribute(value)::')
        console.log(trixEditor.getAttribute('value'))

        @this.set('value', trixEditor.getAttribute('value'));
    })


    addEventListener("trix-file-accept", function(event) {
        if (! mimeTypes.includes(event.file.type) ) {
            // file type not allowed, prevent default upload
            return event.preventDefault();
        }
    });

    addEventListener("trix-attachment-add", function(event){
        console.log('trix-attachment-addm event::')
        console.log(event)

        uploadTrixImage(event.attachment);
    });

    function uploadTrixImage(attachment){
        console.log('uploadTrixImage attachment::')
        console.log(attachment)

        // upload with livewire
    @this.upload(
        'photos',
        attachment.file,
        function (uploadedURL) {
            console.log('uploadTrixImage uploadedURL::')
                             console.log(uploadedURL)

            const trixUploadCompletedEvent = `trix-upload-completed:${btoa(uploadedURL)}`;
            const trixUploadCompletedListener = function(event) {
                console.log('987 event::')
                console.log(event)

                attachment.setAttributes(event.detail);
                window.removeEventListener(trixUploadCompletedEvent, trixUploadCompletedListener);
            }

            window.addEventListener(trixUploadCompletedEvent, trixUploadCompletedListener);

            // call the Trix Component @completeUpload below
        @this.call('completeUpload', uploadedURL, trixUploadCompletedEvent);
        },
        function() {},
        function(event){
            attachment.setUploadProgress(event.detail.progress);
        },
    )
 }


</script>


The component above works ok when it is located on one page/component( which is opened by url) and I see console messages from lines :
    console.log('trixEditor::')
    console.log(trixEditor)

But it does not work with crud page when listing/editor area  is controlled by $updateMode var - I suppose as I do not open it when page is opened.
How that can be salved ?
